ClickHouse. Отфильтровать таблицу на удаленном сервере по локальной выборке
Есть таблица phone_bases на локалке и таблица scoring_last на удаленном хосте. Мне нужно отфильтровать таблицу scoring_last по телефонам, полученным из локальной таблицы phone_bases:
SELECT *
FROM phone_bases b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        remote(<хост удаленного клика>, 'scoring', 'scoring_last', <юзер удаленного клика>, <пароль удаленного клика>)
    where
        phone in (
            SELECT phone 
            FROM phone_bases
            where base_id = 46
        )
) sl
ON b.phone = sl.phone
WHERE b.base_id = 46

Дополнительный фильтр внутри left join сделан для ускорения выполнения запроса, т.к. справа джоинится очень большая таблица, и это занимает колоссальное время. Проблема в том, что тело этого фильтра хочет выполниться на удаленном хосте, а не на локалке (пытается найти таблицу phone_bases, которая существует только на локалхосте). Есть ли способ явно указать, откуда делать select?

тело этого фильтра хочет выполниться на удаленном хосте, а не на локалке Наоборот. тело фильтра выполняется на удалённом хосте. Но надо ему объяснить, что внутренний подзапрос должен выполниться на удалённом для него хосте - том, который для основного запроса базовый. Скорее всего, для этого придётся на удалённом хосте создавать обращающееся к удалённому хосту представление.
